# Sets, functions, into, onto.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let A={1,2,...n} and let B={1,2}.
How many functions are there which map A into B?
How many of these functions map A onto B?
My answer:
There are 2n functions which map A into B. 
There are n functions which map A onto B.
Is this correct?

Comment: Do you mean $2n$ or $2^n$?

Comment: Its 2n i.e 2 times n.

Comment: All right, well that's wrong. See my answer below.

Comment: @user5273591 $2n$ would count how many elements there are in the cartesian product $A\times B$.  It is worth mentioning that if $B$ were larger, the second question would be made more difficult.  There is a generic formula however, see [Stanley's Twelvefold Way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way#Surjective_functions_from_N_to_X).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you meant to write, but what you *did* write is wrong.

There will be $2^n$ total maps from $A$ to $B$, since we must choose between two elements of $B$ for each element of $A$.

There will be exactly $2$ maps that are **not** onto.  Which ones are these?

Comment: Yes, got the thing. Thank you.